# Extract a string on a text file using VBS

Tags: regex, string, vbscript, text-files

Okay so I have this file sample.txt

```
("checkAssdMobileNo1".equals(ACTION)
("checkAssdMobileNo2".equals(ACTION)
("checkAssdMobileNo3".equals(ACTION)
("checkAssdMobileNo4".equals(ACTION)
("checkAssdMobileNo5".equals(ACTION)
("checkAssdMobileNo6".equals(ACTION)
```

How can I output only these:

```
checkAssdMobileNo1
checkAssdMobileNo2
checkAssdMobileNo3
checkAssdMobileNo4
checkAssdMobileNo5
checkAssdMobileNo6
```

I tried using the following code but it would not output anything and I couldn't figure out what I did wrong:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set file = objFSO.OpenTextFile("sample.txt" , ForReading)  
Const ForReading = 1

Dim re
Set re = new regexp
re.Pattern = """\w+?""[.]equals(ACTION)"
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global = True

Dim line
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
    line = file.ReadLine
    For Each m In re.Execute(line)
       Wscript.Echo m.Submatches(0)
    Next
Loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is close, but missing 2 things:

- You need to escape the parentheses surrounding `ACTION`
- You need to use unescaped parentheses to extract the group between the quotes

Something like this should work:

```
re.Pattern = """(\w+?)""[.]equals\(ACTION\)"
```

Comment: How can I extract the first word (GIISAssuredFacadeService) here: `GIISAssuredFacadeService giisAssuredService = (GIISAssuredFacadeService) APPLICATION_CONTEXT.getBean("giisAssuredFacadeService");`

Comment: @ladiesman1792 It sounds like you have a separate question.  Instead of adding it as a comment here, could you create a separate question on this site?  I'd also recommend looking to see if there's already information available on using regular expressions to extract the first word from a line of text.

Answer (score 1):

Regex you need is

```
\("(\w+)"
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pW8yE3/1)

It uses the concept of [Group Capture](http://regexone.com/lesson/11)